# How do I add carriage return to the beginning of my tramp-shell-prompt-pattern?

Tags: emacs, tramp

I am using a new server that when sshing into requires me the press "return" in order to see my shell prompt.  I believe this is causing my emacs tramp to get hung up.  When I tried to open a file through tramp on the new server I am repeatedly asked for the password.  I read that this could be due to tramp not recognizing the prompt.  The prompt is the same as on other servers that work, which makes me think it is this  that is causing issues.

I'm thinking the solution would be to add carriage return to the variable tramp-shell-prompt-pattern.  How would I do this?

maybe something like:

```
(setq tramp-shell-prompt-pattern "\r\(?:^\|\)[^]#$%> ]*#?[]#$%>] *\(\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z] *\)*")
```

adding \r to the front of the default?

---

Also, I don't know if it will be possible to remove this behavior on the server side.  I tried creating a .hushlogin file in my home directory, but it had no effect.

---

I came across this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/179313/tramp-waiting-for-prompts-from-remote-shell) which addresses the problem of the shell requiring user input.  The solution didn't work

```
(setq tramp-shell-prompt-pattern "^[^$>\n]*[#$%>] *\\(\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z] *\\)*")
```

Thanks for your help.  Clearly I'm a novice.

Comment: `tramp-shell-prompt-pattern` is just a regex that matches text to determine when a prompt is present, not something that can take action.  I'm not sure how you would configure tramp to do this, but I'm fairly certain you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: thanks for the comment.  I was afraid that was the case.  I will look more into disabling the need to supply a "return" to get the prompt.

Comment: Is the required "return" in order to answer a question/prompt? If so and it's a yes/no or y/n question (or if it doesn't matter what you enter), tramp might have you covered with its `tramp-yesno-prompt-regexp` and `tramp-yn-prompt-regexp` options. You can also increase `tramp-verbose` to see what it thinks is going on...

Comment: The administrator was able to revise to login so that no "return" was required to see the prompt.  I think there was a typo of sorts on his end creating the welcome message in the bashrc.